# bootstrap 4 pills not changing color when clicked

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use [this](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/3078089?action=prism_export#html-tab-view) bootstrap pills example but there is no javascript or css that goes along with it. How do I go about highlighting the pills that is clicked. In the example when the pill is clicked it turns purple. I am trying something like the below but it does not work. Thank you.

```
$('#nav-link').on('click', function(e) {
  this.backgroundColor = 'black';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should toggle a class that sets background.

#### js

```
 $('#navbar #nav-link').removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass('active');
```

*#navbar* is id of your nav-bar.

#### css

```
.active { 
    background: black;
}
```

```js
$("#navbar").on("click", "li", function(e) {
  $('#navbar ul li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm" id="navbar">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-list-2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```